# Does each race in Starcraft 2 Share The Same MMR

Tags: starcraft-2

I have been playing Starcraft 2 with Zerg mainly, I reached my 1000 wins with zerg and now I am starting out with Terran.

Will my MMR transfer to Terran as I am a master league Zerg player? I have been practicing off the ladder with Terran but I know I will most definitly get wiped off the ladder when I start because of my former Zerg MMR.

Do I have to lose a ton to bring it down?

Comment: I haven't found anything authoritative, but a Google search has a ton of threads complaining about MMR not being race independent so it doesn't look good.

Comment: Oh well it looks like I will have to learn the hard way. Straight into the deep end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MMR is not based off of race. A lot of people have been asking Blizzard to introduce MMR decay for races that you don't play. Basically every forum post gets bumped who ask for this feature.

Any MMR changes will be listed in the patch notes, so if a new patch is released you'll find your new information there.

Comment: I had a look around the sc2 forums and they all pretty much summed up to the same thing. Oh well. Thanks

Comment: I know, it really sucks. Good luck to you my friend. En taro arqade!

Comment: If I play on a different server, say americas where my main server is Europe. Will the MMR go to the americas server. Hopefully I can practice terran there.

Comment: I don't believe so. I think you'll start with a "new" MMR. You will, however, experience lag or latency in your commands and that might affect your experience.

Comment: I live at the bottom of the world anyway, I need to connect to the EU server so the latency is common anyway. My ping to the Paris is 180ms all the time. It makes fighting games impossible.